# DotEnv comments are crashing

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I'm using dotenv version 16.0.0 in my NodeJS project but the comment feature that was recently added causes a crash. Without the comments the .env file works perfectly, loading values from it.

The .env file content:

```
# Print out information during runtime, useful for debugging problems not caught. 
(true/false)
VERBOSE=false

# Database settings, update for actual deployment environment
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=TINY_DUCK
DB_NAME=user_database
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

The command to run the NodeJS project is:

```
mocha -r .env ./tests/testManager.js --exit
```

And the error message I get when running the NodeJS project:

```
× ERROR: C:\Users\thega\Source\Repos\network\.env:1
# Print out information during runtime, useful for debugging problems not caught. (true/false)
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at exports.requireOrImport (C:\Users\thega\source\repos\network\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:60:20)
    at async exports.handleRequires (C:\Users\thega\source\repos\network\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:94:28)
    at async C:\Users\thega\source\repos\network\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:353:25
```

Comment: It looks to me as if you are trying to import the `.env` file as JS module instead of loading it with the dotenv package...

Comment: @CherryDT I use the code "require('dotenv').config();" to load the .env file. It works fine without the comments in the .env file.

Comment: I don't think so because even with the comments the file is not valid JavaScript due to the unquoted strings. (with only the boolean and the numbers it could "work" without crashing but create global variables instead, but either way this is not the right way to load the file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are trying to import the `.env` file as JS module instead of loading it with the dotenv package.

The `-r` flag to `mocha` means "require":

> This will require a module before loading the user interface or test files.
>
> It is useful for:
>
> - Test harnesses
> - Assertion libraries that has augment built-ins or global scope (such as should.js)
> - Instant ECMAScript modules using esm
> - Compilers like Babel via @babel/register or TypeScript using ts-node (using --require ts-node/register).

So it will try to load the file as JavaScript and of course that can't work.

Instead, you can require `dotenv/config` so it will parse the file for you and update `process.env` accordingly:

```sh
mocha -r dotenv/config ./tests/testManager.js --exit
```

Or, if you already do `require('dotenv').config()` in your code, you don't need any `-r` switch here at all.